# Unify methods with the same erasure type

Tags: java, type-erasure

There are many answers here, that explain why this code bellow will not work. Although you might argue with the design and proposing solutions to use inheritance, I still would like to see if the compilation error can be addressed differently.

As both *transform* functions are identical, just iterating over a generic set, I guess there must be an option how to unify them. Any idea how to do it?

This code bellow will not compile: *Method transform(Set) has the same erasure transform(Set) as another method in type Example*

```
public class Example {
public static Set<A> transform(Set<A> items) {
    Set<A> itemsSet = new HashSet<A>();
    for (A item : items) {
        itemsSet.add(process(item));
    }
    return itemsSet;
}

public static Set<B> transform(Set<B> items) {
    Set<B> itemsSet = new HashSet<B>();
    for (B item : items) {
        itemsSet.add(process(item));
    }
    return itemsSet;
}

public static A process(A v) {
    //Some code here 
    return v;
}

public static B process(B v) {
    //Some different code here
    return v;
}

class A{}
class B{}
```

}

Comment: Visitor pattern. Or take a `Function` that does the processing.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because at run-time both generics are erased, and you're left with `java.lang.Object`. You could name your methods differently.